Trying to use protocols and TabView in SwiftUI: "Type 'any <Protocol>' cannot conform to 'Hashable'"
I am trying to use several objects that conform to a custom protocol in a TabView with SwiftUI. The problem is, when I write the below code, I get this error on the TabView:
Type 'any Target' cannot conform to 'Hashable'
How can I fix this issue? My code is below:
protocol Target {
    var id: Int { get }
    var name: String { get }
}

struct Target1: Target {
    var id: Int = 1
    var name: String = "Target1"
}

struct Target2: Target {
    var id: Int = 2
    var name: String = "Target2"
}

struct Target3: Target {
    var id: Int = 3
    var name: String = "Target3"
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let targets: [any Target] = [Target1(), Target2(), Target3()]
    @State private var selectedTarget: any Target = Target1()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTarget) { // This is where the error occurs.
                ForEach(targets, id: \.id) { target in
                    Text(target.name)
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
        }
    }
}


The error message says what it means and means what it says.
TabView(selection:) takes as its parameter a Binding<SelectionValue>, where SelectionValue is a generic placeholder that must be resolved to a type that conforms to the Hashable protocol:
struct TabView<SelectionValue, Content> where SelectionValue : Hashable, Content : View

But selectedTarget is typed as a protocol, Target, and a protocol cannot conform to a protocol. Thus you cannot say selection: $selectedTarget.

The ForEach identifies its contents using the .id of each item. The type of this id is Int.
The code compiles and works if you change the type of selectedTarget to the same type as being used for the .id in the ForEach:
@State private var selectedTarget: Int = 1

